# Which performs better: Fewer rule declarations or fewer property declarations?

Tags: css, performance, browser, responsive

In examples of responsive CSS, it's common to see the approach where one UI layout is fully declared as the 'default' layout (i.e. not in a media query), and then a media query adds properties and/or **overrides** those properties to create a different layout/appearance.

**Like this:**

```css
/**** Small screen layout: ****/

.toolbar {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;                  /**** Declared here for the default layout ****/
    position: absolute;           /**** Declared here for the default layout ****/
}

/**** Large screen layout: ****/

@media (min-width: 500px) 
{
    .toolbar {
        position: relative;       /**** Declared again, just to 'remove' it ****/
        width: auto;              /**** Declared again, just to 'remove' it ****/
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
}
```

**I want to do this: Only common properties declared outside media queries**

```css
/**** Common properties ****/

.toolbar {
    background-color: #000;
}

/**** Small-screen-only properties: ****/

@media (max-width: 499px) 
{
    .toolbar {
        width: 100%;            /**** Only declared once, where required ****/
        position: absolute;     /**** Only declared once, where required ****/
    }
}

/**** Large-screen-only properties: ****/

@media (min-width: 500px) 
{
    .toolbar {
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
}
```

I want to use the second approach because I prefer to work like this, **but it has more selectors for the browser to parse**.

Therefore, is the second approach is likely to be significantly worse for performance in a real world scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Hei. Before applying some media queries over the page let's think about how the second approach works.
It applies a white color over all the page and then in those 2 specific cases, one the opposite of the other, it applies other styling. So is "overdoing" CSS, because in this case if the first media query rule is not applied, the second will.

What I do advise you to do, is to set up a general rule with no queries around it. and after it, set up specific queries

So at the end (an example below) is better to do like this

```
.element{
  width:100px;
  height:auto;
  color:#fff;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) 
{
  .element{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    color:#000;
  }
}
```

instead of this

```
@media (max-width: 499px) 
{
  .element{
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    color:#fff;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) 
{
  .element{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    color:#000;
  }
}
```

and whenever you have multiple queries you have to worry about, simply write what you really need. Don't overdo queries making, for example, 2 of them for 1 case

is like an `if/else`. You write the if, because the if will overwrite the default property, but you don't write an else, because the default will remain like so it is not overwritten by the if

**EDIT**

In the possible confusion of all written above. In shorts is better to have a single default style to apply, that is out of any query or condition. Then, other queries that would edit it's behavior will be written below it.

So what I wrote as the first example is the most efficient, the simplest and the best one, also for performance impact at any scale. Plus, I highly advice to use `@media` queries only with `max-width`attributes, because is their purpose to scale the web page based on lower width deviced

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand the logic of writing it like this, but my question is about performance. In your first example the browser will have to parse the selector twice and and apply its properties twice, whereas in the second example it will presumably only have to parse the selector once, since only one of the queries will be true? At the scale of a full UI, might this have a significant performance impact?

Comment: After further reading, I think I understand that the browser parses every selector in the document, regardless of whether the media query is false, so writing fewer selectors overall would seem to be the better practice.

Comment: In the first example (the one with 1 query) you are making a default CSS and only when some specific width applies, the other CSS will apply. in the second case, you are making multi queries that have to be checked. So at the end, making a standard that is always working regarding of the query, is simpler and more efficient than making a multiple query structured CSS sheet